# Can not find definition for element 'document'

Tags: java, php, xml, soap, apache-axis

I try to make a SOAP call and one of the parameters is a xml itself. My call looks like this:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
  xmlns:ns1="vasws.GPAuftrag" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
  xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" 
  SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <ns1:insertOrder>
    <xmlAuftrag>
        <![CDATA[<?xml version="1.0" ?>
        <document>
            <header><client>029</client></header>
            <body><test>1</test></body>
        </document>]]>
    </xmlAuftrag>
    <ziel xsi:type="xsd:string">PISTEST</ziel>
    </ns1:insertOrder>
</SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

In return I get an pharsing error:

> Can not find definition for element 'document'

I guess I have to somehow define what `document` but I don't know how. I do have an `order.xsd` for validating the inner xml. Maybe I have to use this somehow?

The SOAP call goes to an axis2 system if that's any help. In the API definitions I was given only `<header>` and `<body>` was defined as well as the function call `insertOrder(xmlAuftrag, ziel)` but not how to connect them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Searching through the `order.xsd` file I found this:

```
<xs:element name="message">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="header" type="headerType"/>
            <xs:element name="body" type="bodyType"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

This means `<document>` needs to be replaced with `<message>`.